# SSH for git not available in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssh

I have posh-git installed. In git bash **ssh -v** works, but with powershell it doesnt. What am I missing, and what should I do.

I get the following error in powershell as I type **ssh -v** in powershell

```
ssh : The term 'ssh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1 + ssh -v
+ ~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ssh:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Verify that C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin is in your path (on a 64bits machine). Try to type $env:Path in a powershell windows.

Comment: Wow..That was it...Thank You so much..

Comment: And fix by running this command: $env:Path +=";C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"

Comment: hi refer this link for ssh issue- [link] (http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/need-an-ssh-client-on-windows-dont-use-putty-or-cygwinuse-git) the author has tutored nicely for resolution

Answer (score 2):

Add **C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin** to **PATH** system variable